# Check for null value in returned field from MVC Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, if-statement, model

In my details view I have

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OOB_Management)
```

I would like to check if the above is `null` or not, if it isn't null then return the table structure

Whats the best way to check using `@if` statement?

Comment: On a side note, having this kind of logic in the view might not be your best option. Whatever is important to the view should probably be prepared by the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way

```
@if(Model.OOB_Management != null){
       @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OOB_Management)
}
```